# Elm decrement counter while iterating array

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I've recently decided to take a more in depth look at functional programming and I decided to start out with Elm.

I'm very inexperienced at this so I feel like I am actually fighting the concept and the language and that my thought process is all wrong so I was hoping someone could help me with my simple exercises.

I'm trying to create a Minesweeper game, and for starters, I was just trying to populate a grid with mines.

Here's my code so far

```
import Array exposing (Array)


type State = Hidden | Tagged | Revealed
type alias Cell = {isMine: Bool, nearbyMines: Int, state: State}
type alias Board = Array (Array Cell)

mines : Int
mines = 100

initCell : Cell
initCell = 
  {isMine = False, nearbyMines = 0, state = Hidden}

generate : Int -> Int -> Board
generate lines cols =
  Array.initialize lines (\y -> 
    Array.initialize cols (\x -> initCell))


markAsMine : Int -> Int -> Cell -> Cell
markAsMine x y cell =         
    if mines > 0
    then {cell | isMine = True}
    else cell

fillMines : Int -> Board -> Board
fillMines amount board =
  board
    |> Array.indexedMap (\y row -> row |> Array.indexedMap (\x cell-> markAsMine x y cell))
```

Of course, all this will do is mark every cell as a mine, so how do decrement the counter every time I mark a cell as mine? 
This should be something trivial, hence why I think I'm struggling with the different programming paradigm!

Thanks in advance for any help,
Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more functional approach would try to avoid using state when possible. Instead of thinking about it in terms of traversing a set of cells and decrementing a stateful field telling you how many mines are yet to be placed, it would be more idiomatic to pass in a [`Set`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Set#Set) of `(x, y)` values that have already been determined to be mines.

```elm
import Set exposing (Set)

fillMines : Int -> Set ( Int, Int ) -> Board -> Board
fillMines amount mines board =
    board
        |> Array.indexedMap
            (\y row ->
                row |> Array.indexedMap (\x cell -> { cell | isMine = Set.member ( x, y ) mines })
            )
```

You then shift the responsibility of determining which `(x, y)` cells are mines to elsewhere in the application, and since Minesweeper is a randomized game, you'll probably want to create a random set of cells assigned as mines. The type signature could look something like this:

```elm
import Random

minefieldGenerator : Int -> Int -> Int -> Random.Generator (Set (Int, Int))
minefieldGenerator lines cols numMines = ...
```

The implementation of `minefieldGenerator` is outside the scope of this question, but you can use this generator using [`Random.generate`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Random#generate) (which will let the Elm Architecture generate a random number when returned from inside an `update` function), or you can pass in a known seed value to execute [`step`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Random#step).